# Rails: create relationships from external model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationships

I did a search about this, and any kind of "Rails relationships" query a lot options, but I could not find my kind of case..

Can you please suggest the best way to implement this kind of relationships..

**Parent** can create **Connection** for his **Kid**.

I currently have three models - **Parent**, **Kid** and **Connection** (for storing data about **Kid**'s connections)..

Parent:

```
has_many :kids
```

Kid:

```
belongs_to :parent
has_many :connections, :foreign_key => "connector_id"
has_many :connected_to, :through => :connections, :source => :connected
```

Connection:

```
attr_accessible :connected_id
belongs_to :connector, :class_name => "Kid"
belongs_to :connected, :class_name => "Kid"
```

**Parent** is able to create **Kids**.. I am struggling with the best way to teach **Parent** to create *Connections** for his **Kids**..

Any suggestions are really appreciated..

**UPDATE**:

After looking into the  advice by cug, I have the following:

in **Parent**:
    has_many :kids

```
def add_kid_connection(new_kid)
 kids.each do |kid|
   star.linked_by << new_kid
 end
```

end

in view for the _connect_kid.html.erb helper method:

```
<%= form_for current_parent.add_kid_connection(@new_kid) do |f|%>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label "Connect it!" %><br />
<%= f.text_field :new_id %>
<div class="actions"> <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

in ***kids_controller***:

```
def show
 @kid = Kid.find(params[:id])      
 @new_kid = Kid.find(params[:new_id])
```

In the end I get  *Couldn't find Kid without an ID* error for the new_kid line..

Apparently it's something basic, but still trying to figure out...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for example you can add following method for adding some Kid to all Connections of Kids of some parent

```
class Parent
  def add_kid_connection(new_kid)
    kids.each do |kid|
      kid.connected_to << new_kid
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! although I am not sure how to implement this. I am not declaring kids inside Parent model. thus this code leads to some errors and or change in model structure?

Comment: You have `has_many :kids` in your Parent model. This call adds several methods to the model, one of them is `kids`, it returns all associated Kid models. You can read about associations in more details at [ruby on rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: Oh thanks, somehow it started to work.. I actually think I am getting closer - can you please look at the update (above)?

Comment: Your code is very strange, you are using the `form_for` helper in a wrong way and trying to tie the form with show action. I strongly recommend you to read rails guides, as it seems you have some troubles with understanding rails basics.

Comment: Ah, I am trying to adjust the railstutorial to my needs, but looks like I made a wrong turn